# Confirmed but not reflecting /decode?

Tags: blockchain

This transaction was confirmed but i never received the btc.
It shows as valid transfer ,57Btc 
Is this transaction real or fake.
All the information can be found.Hash,Block,Conf. etc but i'm still waiting.
Question .Do i just wait ?
How to clear and receive Btc?
Did The total get sent?
Is this a test transaction ?
Help need to know whats going to happen?

Transaction I.D
222a2290e68c7cd5861e34133a43b10c6ae4732518078b5cbbba1424c84ad8e1

to Wallet 
17tmL8Jsa4Hv9ZVVwtKCgrpqr1TbaNxgMp

Thx

Comment: First of all what, did you send the transaction yourself, what wallet did you use?

Comment: it was from someone else sent to mine but i see that these transactions are requesting the same amount sent back to the unknown wallet from which it came from.

Comment: Think its just Test accounts run

Answer (score 2):

The transaction has a lot of outputs. On of the outputs is the address you mentioned. The tx lookup in www.blockchain.info says, that 0.0579332 BTC was sent successfully with 2175 confirmations (as per today) to 17tmL8Jsa4Hv9ZVVwtKCgrpqr1TbaNxgMp.

There is also a "return address", which transfers 57.68039601 BTC to a SegWit address (bc1qgukqed6kdae4hjgdz9cm7xhrp2mu39054mwa2m). So I assume the funds come from an exchange or similar institution.

If you are the owner of the address 17tmL8Jsa4Hv9ZVVwtKCgrpqr1TbaNxgMp (aka: you have the private key for this address), then you own these funds, and can spend it.